# Audio Device access on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, kernel

I have a device (Lynx) which can take audio from 8 mice and saves the files into my machine using graph edit.
In windows they provide driver and I can access mice and can save files.
I want to do the same on a Mac. Here how I will access this device. I don't have a driver.
Its a PCI card.

Can anyone provide some valuable help
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you get audio from mice?

Comment: @gabe: From their ears. (http://phenome.jax.org/phenome/protodocs/Zheng1/imgs/MouseEar.jpg)

Comment: I have a device called lynx its giving input from mice..
Its a pci device

Comment: @sijith - do you mean one of these products - http://www.lynxstudio.com/product_section.asp?i=2? In which case, I think perhaps you mean "mics" as an abbreviation of microphones, rather than "mice" (which, in English, is the plural of mouse)

Comment: yes sir.... This link only... My card is lynx AES16.
I want to use this card with MAC

Answer (score 1):

Download the drivers from [www.lynxstudio.com](http://www.lynxstudio.com) and the card should just show up in CoreAudio in the same way as the built-in Mac audio devices. There is sample code at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) for recording audio via CoreAudio.